# How can I copy files from a RDC PC to my Mac

Tags: mac, file-sharing

I need to copy some files from a RDC PC to my MAC. I can copy files from RDC to a PC but not to a mac. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: What app are you using to connect to the PC from your Mac? Microsoft Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

You could map a folder on the local Mac to the PC and then just move files using the PC copy interface. That's probably the simplest and works across many versions of windows and OS X as well as regardless of the network configuration.

You could set up a proper network share on the PC or Mac as well, but that's more work for little payoff.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Internet connectivity (who doesn't these days), you can use a Cloud Service to create a shared filespace that you can not only use between computers, you can use between computers located essentially anywhere.

My favorite is [OneDrive](http://onedrive.com), but I have also used [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/), [Box](https://www.box.com/), and [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/business/landing-t61fl?_tk=sem_b_bing&_camp=sem-b-bing-dropbox-us-eng%7Cdropbox%7Cexact&_kw=dropbox%7Ce&_ad=10994324030).

These are all cross platform (OS X, iOS, Android, Windows (7, 8, 10, Server, Linux and even Windows Phone).